# retrieve different values from a single string with regular expressions and python

Tags: python, string

Suggest that I have this:

```
valuestringdate = "24/6/2010"
```

and I want to get something like this from the variable

```
day = 24
month = 6
year = 2010
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: solved:

With something like this:
var1 = "stringdate"
only needs to do that:
print var1[:4]
stri

Comment: That's not nearly flexible enough; you have far better solutions in the answers. Try doing that with dates that have a mix of different days and  months (including 1 and 2 digits), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .split() method.
In this case, 
`dateList = valuestringdate.split("/")`
Which would produce list: `dateList = ["24","6","2010]`

Using indexes:
`day = dateList[0]` would set `day = "24"`

From there you can use `day = int(day)` to convert the day from a string to an integer.

You should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 2):

You could just `split` the string:

```
day, month, year = valuestringdate.split('/')
```